# How to update a mysql table after adding an @OneToMany relationship to it in JPA entity?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have a spring/jpa project that uses a mysql database. I have updated an already existent entity so that it has a new @OneToMany relationship with a new table that I have created (Which has an @ManyToOne annoation). I have gotten this to work with an embedded database with unit tests and is working properly. But when I try and deploy it to my development server, it seems that the mapping is not registered, and the data just returns a list with size 0 when it should return more.

The function that I call is

```
public List<Recommendation> getRecommendationsByEmployeeId()
```

I belive that this issue is related to some JPA magic that is done when creating a database, that does not occur when deployed against an already existent one. Is this right to assume? Or Why would this work when running my tests against an embedded database but not against the already existent development database?

These are the relevant entities.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "recommendation")
    public class Recommendation extends BusinessEntity {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="employeeid")
        @JsonBackReference
        //This is simply to avoid a stackoverflow error 
        private Employee employee;

//New relationship
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recommendation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonBackReference
        List<RecommendationImage> recommendationimages;

        public Recommendation(){}

        public Recommendation(Employee employee, String title, String description, double targetLat, double targetLong,
                              String street, String city, String country
                              ) {
            this.employee = employee;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.targetLat = targetLat;
            this.targetLong = targetLong;
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
            this.active = true;
        }


        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }

        public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
        }

        public List<RecommendationImage> getRecommendationimages() {
            return recommendationimages;
        }

        public void setRecommendationimages(List<RecommendationImage> recommendationimages) {
            this.recommendationimages = recommendationimages;
        }
    }
```

New entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recommendationimage")
public class RecommendationImage extends ImageEntity{

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="recommendationid")
        private Recommendation recommendation;

        public RecommendationImage(){}

        public RecommendationImage(Recommendation recommendation, String path){
            this.recommendation = recommendation;
            this.path = path;
        }

        public Recommendation getRecommendation() {
            return recommendation;
        }

        public void setRecommendation(Recommendation recommendation) {
            this.recommendation = recommendation;
        }




    }
```

Any help with this issue would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I assume you create/update tables in your embedded database using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create (or update). Is that also the case for your MySQL database?